# Choice and the principle of transfinite induction

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice, transfinite-induction

Does the Axiom of Choice suffice to show Transfinite Induction in ZF?

Also, if possible, could you please give some general remarks/insight on *(i)* worthwhile noting equivalencies or dependencies between Axiom of Choice (stronger/weaker related forms) and Transfinite Induction or, in particular, *(ii)* if PA consistency proofs (like Gentzen's, in PRA+'Quantifier Free Transfinite Induction up to ε0') require any form of Axiom of Choice.

Comment: Transfinite induction does not require any choice.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of constructions by transfinite recursion? Here, choice is definitely invoked in general.

Comment: Thanks! I was considering the specific case of Gentzen's proof of consistency of PA, and then also in general in ZF. Can Transfinite Induction be proved or disproved it in ZFC? Or is it possible to show independence of it from ZFC?

Comment: Transfinite induction can be proved in ZF (it does not require the C as Andres said). Gentzen's proof of consistency can be formalized in ZF and proven there. There is also a more routine proof of consistency of PA that can be done in ZF, namely proving that $\omega$ is a model of PA (and proving that any theory that has a model is consistent). Gentzen's proof is in a much weaker system than ZF, which is part of its appeal.

Comment: What is your precise statement of "Transfinite Induction"?

Comment: Well-founded recursion, whether countable or not, also does not require AC

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Gentzen's proof can be formalized in PRA plus "transfinite induction on $\epsilon_0$", provided the latter is phrased in the right way. It does not require set theory of any sort, much less the axiom of choice.  As mentioned by spaceisdarkgreen in the comments, this is one reason (among many) that Gentzen's proof is of interest.

However, as a separate point, "PA is consistent" is a $\Pi^0_1$ sentence, and a sentence of that form provable in ZFC is always provable in ZF as well, so even if we look at ZFC there is no way that proving the consistency of PA could require the axiom of choice. Even if choice were used to simplify a ZFC proof that PA is consistent, the use of choice could be eliminated.

Comment: Thanks! I understand the Principle of Transfinite Induction is a theorem of ZF alone then. Can PA's consistency be proved in PRA + 'Some (weaker/stronger) Form of AC' (if there's any *ad hoc* to PRA)?

Comment: It doesn't really make sense to try to add an axiom of choice to PRA.

Answer (score 0):

The validity of transfinite induction is established with basically the same proof as for ordinary induction: if there is a counterexample, there must be a least counterexample, but the proof form demonstrates such a thing cannot exist.

The role of the axiom of choice is to allow a *specific type of step* that one often uses in inductive proofs. For example, one proof that every vector space mimics the usual algorithm for "constructing" a basis that one often sees in finite dimensional linear algebra:

1. Start with the empty set.
2. If your set spans the whole vector space, it's a basis and you can stop.
3. Choose a vector that isn't in the span of your set.
4. Add that vector to the set you're constructing and go back to step 2.

The role of the axiom of choice is to prove that step 3 is actually something that you can use in a transfinite "algorithm" such as this.

Comment: You seem to be mixing up induction and recursion, which is probably going to be confusing to some. Also, there is a small typo in your second paragraph (you forgot to say a proof of what). Also, it is not clear what that argument illustrates; it is not inductive.